# High speed bit bang GPIO reading

Tags: gpio, serial, uart, pigpio, bit-bang

I'm trying to establish a UART communication link by means of bit-banging. For the TX part, I am using the pigpio lib to form a 1Mbaud wave of bits ([gpioWaveAddSerial](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/cif.html#gpioWaveAddSerial)). I have checked it and it with an oscilloscope and it performs as intended.

The problem is that for the receiving end, the same lib happens to limit the baud rate to 250000([gpioSerialReadOpen](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/cif.html#gpioSerialReadOpen)).
Is there a way to read a bit wave at 1 Mbaud rate?

Comment: @Philippos pigpio doesn't use interrupts, it uses DMA to sample the GPIO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not remember why the limit is 250k rather than say 500k or 1000k.  I expect there was a reason.  It may simply have been there was too much jitter at the higher bit rates to reliably clock the data.

I suggest you have a look at the code and examine the consequences of changing the constant PI_BB_SER_MAX_BAUD to 1000000.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It appears that higher rates are quite unreliable. On to another solution then.